# 3D point cloud in python

Tags: python, 3d, package, processing, point-cloud-library

I am kind of new here :)  Try to be concise,
I am trying to pip install packages required for point cloud processing but I get these errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pclpy (from versions: none)  
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pclpy  
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.  
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Although I updated the pip I got the warning as well. Thanks

Comment: From the [PyPI help page](https://pypi.org/help/#tls-deprecation): "If you are having trouble with `pip install` and get a `No matching distribution found` or `Could not fetch URL` error, try adding `-v` to the command to get more information: `pip install --upgrade -v pip`"

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

As you can see in the [pclpy](https://pypi.org/project/pclpy/) official site, currently [it does not work](https://github.com/davidcaron/pclpy#linux) with Linux. Assuming you're using Linux, that explains the error you encountered.

For point cloud processing library in Python, you might want to have a look at [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/). To install it, you just have to type `pip install open3d` in your terminal.

To read point cloud data in and write it out, you can just use a few line of codes:

```py
import open3d as o3d

pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud('./input.pcd')
o3d.io.write_point_cloud('output.ply', pcd)
```

It's very easy to use and contains very good [tutorial](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/index.html). Hope it helps!